# ADO recordset has no recordcount with source set to ADO command (stored procedure)

Tags: sql-server, vba, stored-procedures

I have an ADO command object in VBA running and returning values from a stored procedure (in SQL Server).  To validate the SP and command lines in VBA, I've used the CopyFromRecordset method to view the data and everything seems fine.

```
Set ADOComm = New ADODB.Command
With ADOComm
    .ActiveConnection = ADOConn
    .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    .CommandText = "GenerateMasterSumIfs"
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("ImportFilePath", adVarChar, adParamInput, 100, TextFileSavePath)
End With

Set ADORec = New ADODB.Recordset
Set ADORec = ADOComm.Execute
```

I'd now like to be able to navigate the returned records using FIND or GETROWS  (for example) but the recordset appears to have no data (recordset.RecordCount returns -1).  I've tried to research this online and have seen references to cursor types being restricted depending on the source (in my case, SQL Server) but haven't been able to find a solution that I can understand and use.

So, my question(s), specifically, are:

> 1. Can I continue to use the ADO Command/Recordset combination to collate my data then 'navigate' it? OR
> 2. Do I need to run the SP using a different method to enable the navigation I require?

I'm no expert in this field, so would appreciate your patience with my technical descriptions and any site etiquette faux pas.

Comment: Is `SET NOCOUNT ON;` in your stored procedure?

Comment: It isn't.  I tried adding this to my SP but it made no difference to my situation.  I have, however, since solved my issue (see my answer).  Thanks for your suggestion, though.

Answer (score 1):

The solution I needed was the CursorLocation property of the ADO Connection object.  Changing it to adUseClient has allowed me to move the cursor and use methods such as FIND and GETROWS as I required.

```
Set ADOConn = New ADODB.Connection
ADOConn.CursorLocation = adUseClient   
ADOConn.Open "Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Server=ServerName;Database=DBName;Trusted_Connection=yes;"

Set ADOComm = New ADODB.Command
With ADOComm
    .ActiveConnection = ADOConn
    .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    .CommandText = "GenerateMasterSumIfs"
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("ImportFilePath", adVarChar, adParamInput, 100, TextFileSavePath)
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("MTFilePath", adVarChar, adParamInput, 100, PathToMT)
End With

Set ADORec = New ADODB.Recordset
Set ADORec = ADOComm.Execute
```